# Recursive method in JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, recursion, jquery-plugins

I am trying to develop a JQuery plugin for a series of html select input.
If any select changes, all subsequent selects will be changed/reloaded.

Here is the html -

```
<select id="first"  class="myselect" data-child ="second">...</select>
<select id="second" class="myselect" data-child ="third">..</select>
<select id="third" class="myselect"  data-child ="fourth">...</select>
....

$('.myselect').MySelect();
```

This is my plugin I had so far-

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.MySelect= function () {       
    return this.each(function () {
        var $This = $(this);
        var childId = $This.attr('data-child');           

        $This.change(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (childId !='none') {                    
                var $Child = $('#' + childId); 
               $Child.Reset(); //Should be Recursive call
            }              
        });                   
    });
};

}(jQuery));
```

How can I do it within the plugin?

Comment: or `$Child.MySelect();`?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a custom event that when triggered does whatever reset you want and then triggers change on itself so it cascades down the chain

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.MySelect = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
      var $This = $(this);
      var childId = $This.attr('data-child'),
        $child = childId != 'none' ? $('#' + childId) : null;

      $This.on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $child && $child.trigger('my-reset')
      }).on('my-reset', function(e) {
        $This.val('').trigger('change');
      });

    });
  };

})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('.myselect').MySelect();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first" class="myselect" data-child="second">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2"selected>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="second" class="myselect" data-child="third">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<select id="third" class="myselect" data-child="fourth">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="fourth" class="myselect" data-child="none">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
</select>
```